# Move assignemnt is called instead of copy, when concepts are used for source type

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

In the following code, when I change the source from `CAssign` as source for assignment operators to `AnyThing auto`, then the move constructor will be called instead of copy.

I'm guessing it has to do with constness but I might be wrong. What causes this and how to achieve what I want?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <concepts>

template<typename T>
concept AnyThing = true;

struct CAssign
{
    CAssign() = default;

    CAssign& operator=(const CAssign& source)
    {
        std::cout << "Copy called\n";

        return *this;
    }
    CAssign& operator=(CAssign&& source)
    {
        std::cout << "Move called\n";

        return *this;
    }
};

int main() {
    
    CAssign a1, a2;

    a1 = a2;
}
```

EDIT:
This is the change I do:

```
CAssign& operator=(const AnyThing auto& source)
//...
CAssign& operator=(AnyThing auto&& source)
```

Tried it with both Clang and GCC. Move is called instead of copy.

Comment: Unclear the change you do...

Comment: The C++ compiler is pretty clever, isn't it? It recognizes, that a2 isn't used after the assignment and uses the cheaper move operation instead.

Comment: @tooEarlyToGetUp: C++ doesn't do that.

Comment: @tooEarlyToGetUp In debug mode its not supposed to do that, and my IRL code was lot more complex than this.

Comment: @Jarod42 Don't know how it was unclear but made edits.

Comment: @tooEarlyToGetUp That isn't an allowed optimization as it changes the observable behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
CAssign& operator=(CAssign&& source)
```

the reference parameter is a rvalue reference. It will be called only if the argument given is a rvalue (which it isn't in `a1 = a2;`). This is a move assignment operator and how it should normally behave.

---

With

```
CAssign& operator=(Anything auto&& source)
```

or just

```
CAssign& operator=(auto&& source)
```

this is *not* a rvalue reference parameter. `auto` acts as a short-hand for a template parameter and if a template parameter `T` of a function is used directly as `T&&` for a function parameter, then it is a *forwarding reference*.

The forwarding reference can match either a rvalue or a lvalue. If it matches a rvalue, the function parameter will be a rvalue reference. If it matches a lvalue, it will be a lvalue reference.

In your case `a1 = a2;` the right-hand side is a lvalue and so it will call the specialization

```
CAssign& operator=<CAssign&>(CAssign& source)
```

of the function template that the `auto` version defines. This overload is preferred to the copy assignment overload you defined, because it doesn't require a `const` conversion in the parameter. If you had made `a2`'s type `const`, the copy assignment operator would be preferred, since it is not a function template.

In particular this means that such a `operator=` overload is *not* a move assignment operator (or a copy assignment operator).

---

You shouldn't define a template `operator=` overload that takes any type or if you do, add a constraint that the type doesn't match `CAssign`.

Comment: Thank you! Adding these constraints did the trick for now: `requires (std::is_rvalue_reference_v<decltype(source)>)` and requires `(false == std::is_rvalue_reference_v<decltype(source)>)` respectively. Do you think it is proper solution?

Comment: @Newline I am not sure which of these you put where. But the important point is that a templated `operator=` (no matter how constrained) is never really a move assignment operator and that may cause potential trouble, for example because an implicit move assignment operator will be preferred in overload resolution.

Comment: I see. Thank you!